# CATiledLayer to draw giant UIView with buttons?

Tags: performance, uiview, catiledlayer

I've got this giant `UIView` with around 600 `UIButtons` as subviews. The `UIView` is about 2000 by 2000 pixels and it's a subview on itself for a `UIScrollView`. I'm trying to implement `CATiledLayer` as the rendering layer for this giant `UIView` but I can't seem to figure out how to render the tiles. I found a lot of examples that cover `CATiledLayer` with tiled images, pdf's, ... but I never found a real example on how to draw a complete UIView with a lot of subviews. You're probably asking why i'd like to stick with `UIView`? Because I'd like the users to keep on using the buttons to interact with the view.

I'm wondering if someone has an example or some psuedo code on how to implement the `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context` method, keeping in mind that there's 1 giant `UIView` with a lot of `UIbuttons` as its subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with iOS 4.0, you can use `drawRect:` instead of `drawLayer:inContext:`. This Q&A from Apple explains it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1637/_index.html. The important point from it is that drawRect: in 4 is now thread-safe and you can use UIKit graphics functionality.

You still need to override this method to use a `CATileLayer`:

```
+(Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

But you can now just use `drawRect:`

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //normal drawing routines here.
}
```

The rect that is delivered to the method will be the size of your tiles and you need to determine what needs to be drawn in the particular rect. The power of `CATiledLayer` is that it only calls for drawing the tiles that are showing on the screen. It also uses background threads and is very fast.

I have not used `CATiledLayer` with UIViews, only large images. Are the `UIViews` subclasses with their own `drawRect:` implementations? I think you will need to determine which views will be showing in the current rect and call their `drawRect:` method.

Using `drawRect:` is only for iOS 4.0 and later, it won't work for older versions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm developing for 3.2 or higher on the iPad so this doesn't really answer my question yet. Anyway, a big vote up for the information!

Comment: I wrote a little demo app before I answered using iOS 4. I'll redo it for 3.2 as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question but did you have any luck getting this to work on pre4.0 versions?